# Where to observe application deployed by Jenkins?

Tags: maven, maven-2, jenkins

Question from a first-time Jenkins user. So I hope you wouldn't mind if the question is too silly.

I have installed jenkins on a Ubuntu machine, and is accessible at localhost:8080. I have successfully configured it to work with Maven2 and Git as well. Next, I created a job/project (A Java/Spring application), and got it to build without error on Jenkins as well.

Now my question is, where do I see this application running? :)

Best Regards
James

Comment: Did you specified on which type of server (like Tomcat, JBoss, ...) you want to deploy it ? You need to add a plugin in order to deploy the application and access it.

Comment: No I haven't. I have configured for JDK, Git and Maven only. I seek some help on that one.

Comment: Your Jenkins is running on tomcat ? if yes, easiest way will be to deploy your app on the same instance. have a look at http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: I mean, I have installed Tomcat, but haven't specified that anywhere in Jenkins. Btw, I don't see that option anywhere. Do I need a plugin for that too??

Comment: Yes you do : `http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html` to do it with maven or `https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin` to do it with jenkins

Comment: Thanks @yodamad. That did wonders! Can you post it as an answer for me to accept it?

Comment: Good to hear :) Answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy : http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html to do it with maven or https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin to do it with jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You can see the console output in the running job if you click the running job and look for the link on the left hand side.

Comment: I see something like: [INFO] Building war: /root/.jenkins/workspace/Amadeus/target/Appname-1.0.0.war

Comment: Yes in package phase you build the war, in install phase you copy it in your local repository but not deploying it

Answer (score 0):

Building and deploying are two different things. Jenkins can do the latter for you too but you need to have it configured in your maven project. Typically this is accomplished (for tomcat) using the [tomcat maven plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/index.html)